# long integers in Date validation columnn fields displays as ########

Tags: .net, excel

When i enter 555555555555555555 in a date column with date validation applied displays as ###########

how to avoid long integers in Date validation columnn fields displaying in that format.

I am doing though .NET like

```
worksheet.Range(Range).Validation.Add(XlDVType.xlValidateDate, XlDVAlertStyle.xlValidAlertStop, XlFormatConditionOperator.xlGreaterEqual, Today(), Type.Missing)
worksheet.Range(Range).NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
worksheet.Range(Range).Validation.IgnoreBlank = True
worksheet.Range(Range).Validation.InputTitle = "Excel Validation"
worksheet.Range(Range).Validation.ErrorTitle = "Error in Date"
worksheet.Range(Range).Validation.InputMessage = "Note: only date values here 'm/d/yyyy'"
worksheet.Range(Range).Validation.ErrorMessage = "Enter Date greater than todays"
worksheet.Range(Range).Validation.ShowInput = True
worksheet.Range(Range).Validation.ShowError = True
```

Comment: What do you expect for a date that is about 100,000 times the [age of the universe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Age_of_the_universe)?!

Answer (score 4):

The date is out of range. In Excel the tooltip states

> Dates and times that are negative or too large display as ######.

This is Excel working as designed.

You need to validate your values before adding them to your worksheet. How you handle invalid dates will depend on your application. It might well be that you want to let Excel handle it for you.